# How can I set the periodic range in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not pretty sure which tools in python I can use to set up the periodic boundary conditions. For example, if I have a random value `theta`, I want to examine if it lies in the range `[(4k-1)pi,(4k+1)pi]` (like `...,[-5pi.-3pi],[-pi,pi],[3pi,5pi]...`) (return `True` if it is), where k is any integer. There're infinitely many intervals, how can I determine this condition? I really don't know how I could proceed. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: `return any((4*k-1)*pi <= theta <= (4*k+1)*pi for i in itertools.count() for k in [i, ~i])`

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for the comment!! I tried this but the program just keeps running and doesn't return any result.

Comment: It should "return True if it is", it just won't return otherwise.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks!! Can I make it return 'false' otherwise?

Comment: Look at `theta % (4*pi)` or `theta / pi % 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the **modulo** operation is for:

```
(theta/pi+1)%4<=2
```

The addition shifts the intervals to begin at 0 like `%` does.